# Voltage regulators on series PV panels

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm trying to design a module to go on the backs of panels that will be connected in series. The module will have a few sensors connected to an FPGA and it will modulate a signal onto the line with the data from the sensors. I have that part figured out but the part I'm having difficulty with is figuring out a way to have have a voltage regulator connected to just the panel it's on, regulating power for the FPGA and sensors.

<s>I was using a bench power supply to test out a [little board that utilized LM2596](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01KPRB8L2) that looked to work with a non zero negative (i.e. tested having a supply before it providing power so negative is around 30V and the positive terminal is 60V with another supply adding another 30V).</s>

I am running into issues when I added more than the one coupled to each supply. It overheated fast and then ended up shorting to the current limit on my supply. --EDIT-- (not important because not asking for diagnosing... asking for help with the next statement)

I'm new to this and would love some help with what I should be looking for as far as voltage regulators that are designed for this kind of application without letting out magic smoke. **What I need is help understanding what voltage regulators that can be set up like the schematic below and provide 5V with a decent amount of current (100-200mA). What I used is having issues and before I start ordering parts/evaulation boards I figured I'd ask for input if there is already an industry standard (linear vs switching/if there is some sort of circuit similar to how AC has the diode bridge/other configurations I was unsuccessful in finding) to save time/money.**

Below is a simple schematic to represent what I'm trying to accomplish, where V1&2 are the bench supplies representing the panels (will want to implement this on more than just two if I can get it working), U1&2 are how I need the voltage regulators, and U3&4 are my microcontrollers and sensors *that are not the focus of this question* but will run on 5V and 3.3V and need at most a budget of 100-200mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKcfPH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

--EDIT--
To add some more information about the panels I'm working with -
Pmpp > 240W
Vmpp 30.4V
Impp 7.9A
Voc 37.3V
Isc 8.52A

Comment: *"I am running into issues when I added more than the one coupled to each supply."* This is the point where you lose me. More than one what coupled to what exactly? Show a diagram of your test setup, since that's where the issue is happening. Are you using separate bench supplies to represent individual solar panels?

Comment: Side note: I take it that you're tying to couple a high-frequency signal onto the power bus for communication. But unless you block that high frequency from entering the input of the regulator, it'll just get swallowed up there. At a minimum, put an inductor in series with the + input of each regulator.

Comment: @DaveTweed When I tested it with just one of those regulator boards (link above) with the bench power supplies connected in series it was fine but then I add another onto one of the other power supplies and the one later in the series ends up overheating and shorting.

Also, I have tested a few parts I had spares of: LM2594 and REG1117. they seem to work fine with this setup so I'm not sure why the LM2596 boards were overheating.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes thank you for the inductor suggestion. I have that but just chose not to include it in the schematic since it's not the focus of my question but the suggestion is appreciated as that would cause issues.

Comment: Your **words** are still not clear. **Show us a diagram** of your exact test setup. Don't leave out any details.

Comment: @DaveTweed A simple schematic/diagram for what I'm trying to accomplish is already included at the end my question. When I have V1-3 setup and only put in U1 and U4 it works without issue. Adding in even just U2 without U5 causes issues. It's most likely the design of the step-down modules I am using. U4-6 will change around as I toy with things. What I need are voltage regulators that can be set up like this and provide 5V with a decent amount of current (100-200mA). What I used is having issues and before I start ordering parts/evaulation boards I figured I'd ask for input to save time/money

Comment: @BrownKuma He said "of your exact test setup.  Don't leave out any details".  This is not satisfied by the "simple schematic" and text you have provided.  There are volunteers on here that can often understand your whole circuit after looking at it for only moments or minutes, but when you just provide a link to an undocumented board and a bunch of text without much data in it, people start asking for the missing information.  Each time you provide extra information, edit your question to reflect it.

Comment: People can't help much with undocumented circuit boards like that one, because the PCB traces are hidden and reverse engineering requires a lot of work, but I do notice it doesn't appear to be isolated.  If you get an isolated one and pay attention to where you're attaching any ground references, you'll likely find your problem.  Maybe, anyways.  Hopefully.  I guess, it's just really hard to say without any info.  Hmmm if the connections are as simple as your diagram suggests, is there any circuitry in the panels like a reverse blocking diode or MPPT regulator?

Comment: Also, what are you using to mount the boards?  Plastic standoffs or insulating washers or something like that?

Comment: @KH I agree. What I showed **is my test setup**. I'm **not** asking for help with the board I have. What I said at the end of my last comment is "What I need are voltage regulators that can be set up like this and provide 5V with a decent amount of current (100-200mA). What I used is having issues and before I start ordering parts/evaulation boards I figured I'd ask for input to save time/money"

Comment: My apologies for not asking the question clearly and concisely. I modified my question to strikethrough unneeded information and clarify what I'm asking for.

Comment: You are asking what kind of voltage converters will not have the issues you are having, which requires knowledge of the issue.  One cannot say that something will not go wrong again if one does not know what went wrong in the first place.  Perhaps your voltage injection system is what is actually causing a short or cross connection.  Each voltage converter is built in a different way, but generally speaking, if you have any interconnect between converters with different ground references, isolation might be desired.

Comment: I won't write that as an answer though because it is not remotely certain, just lack of isolation is a likely problem when power supplies that are in series interact.  I was encouraging you to provide the information asked for(or something similar like test rig pictures) because once he has the right information a guy like Dave can tell you a lot more than me, and with greater certainty.  By the way, with your current diagram, so long as there is no connection whatsoever between downstream connections, isolation should not be necessary, but what does that MCU connect to?

Comment: I guess I can also say that if lack of isolation is the issue, a linear regulator, aside from having unacceptable efficiency at higher currents/voltage drops, I don't believe they can have isolation.   Switching converters don't always cost a fortune either, you just have to search a lot for decent ones that don't.  An LDO knocking 30V down to 5V with a 200mA current will consume 5W, requiring a very large heat sink.